# Error: Cannot find module

Tags: javascript, node.js

В папке находится два файла: index.js и script.js
index.js:

```
const script = require('script.js');
script();
```

script.js:

```
module.exports = function() {
    console.log('hello');
}
```

Пишу в консоли `node -v`, ответ: `v14.4.0`
Пишу `node index.js`, в ответ получаю:

```js
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1032
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'script.js'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\kamah\Desktop\Мои работы\Сложный js\index.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1029:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:898:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1089:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:73:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\kamah\Desktop\Мои работы\Сложный js\index.js:1:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1200:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1220:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1049:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ 'C:\\Users\\kamah\\Desktop\\Мои работы\\Сложный js\\index.js' ]
}
```

Что не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо было подключать файл так:

```js
const script = require('./script.js');
```